# How can I export an Excel/OpenOffice/LibreOffice chart to SVG?

Tags: excel, charts, svg, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I'm using one of the popular spreadsheet applications (Excel/OpenOffice/LibreOffice Graph) to create some nice charts.

Is it possible to export the charts to SVG format from any of those programs?

Answer (score 14):

You can use Libreoffice/Openoffice + Inkscape:

1. Create your chart on Calc
2. Copy the chart into Draw
3. Export Draw file to svg (File->Export)
4. Open the svg on Inskcape
5. Right click on the chart and select Ungroup

This way you can edit every single object on the graph like an svg.

Comment: What is Draw? Is it a software? Is it a panel on the program (if so, what program?)?

Comment: @SeuMadruga LibreOffice Draw

Comment: You can skip the part with Libre Draw. Just mark it and `Export...` as an SVG.

Comment: Since LibreOffice 4.0 you can right click a chart and select "Export as Image". [Since LibreOffice 4.1 this also supports SVG](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60137)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/svg-developers/message/17936), there are several ways in Excel:

1. use [svgmaker](http://www.svgmaker.com/product_standard.html) into MS Excel
2. try this [example](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/svg-developers/files/piechart.xls) (mirror [here](http://www.fileserve.com/file/26knXVq/piechart.xls))
3. grab data from Excel in XML and apply an XSLT mask (but seems like quite tricky - here is a [link](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N1755.html) given in the thread)

I don't know enough OpenOffice or LibrOffice to help you more.

Comment: A little clumsy solution for LibreOffice: [Save a chart/graph as image in Calc?](http://ask.libreoffice.org/question/2142/save-a-chartgraph-as-image-in-calc)